# Group By on part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `LOG` that  contains a field `NOTES`. Table `LOG` also contains a field `NrofItems`. This is on Azure SQL.
`NOTES` is a string that contains keyvalue pairs separated by semicolons. The order of the keyvalue pairs is random.

Example of three records:

```
NOTES | NrofItems    
"customer=customer1;code=blablabla;application=SomeApplication"  | 23
"code=blablabla;customer=customer99;application=AlsoApplication" | 33
"code=blablabla;customer=customer1;application=AlsoApplication"  |  2
```

I need to sum the value of `NrofItems` per customer like this:

```
customer1  | 25
customer99 | 33
```

How do I split the string so I get the part after `customer=` until the first following semicolon?
Once I have that I guess a simple group by will do the trick

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use `string_split()`, twice:

```
select s2.value, sum(nrofitems)
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.notes, ';') s1 cross apply
     string_split(s1.value, '=') s2
where s1.value like 'customer=%' and s2.value <> 'customer'
group by s2.value;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd252f08a31d42e9b82391703ea7fc9f) is a db<>fiddle.

Or using `string_split()` once:

```
select stuff(s1.value, 1, 10, ''), sum(nrofitems)
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.notes, ';') s1 
where s1.value like 'customer=%' 
group by stuff(s1.value, 1, 10, '');
```

Comment: Does exactly what it needs to do. Smart solution!. Now, what if I would want to group on more items from the notes? For example, on Application?

Comment: @Henrov . .. I would suggest that you ask a new question.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259157/group-data-on-different-keyvaluepairs-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring()`

```
select left(tt.notes, charindex(';', tt.notes)), sum(t.nroftimes)
from table t cross apply
     ( values (substring(notes, charindex('customer=', notes)+9, len(notes))) 
     ) tt(notes)
group by left(tt.notes, charindex(';', tt.notes));
```